# How to use Bootstrap to align images horizontally so that their tops and bottoms are on the same horizontal line?

Tags: css

[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aataw.png)

```
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-10">
                    <div class="row justify-content-center g-4">
                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-6">
                            <img class="width-10" src="/image-500x500.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-6">
                            <img class="width-10" src="/image-500x500.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-12">
                            <img class="width-10" src="/image-1000x500.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-10">
                    <div class="row justify-content-center"> 
                        <div class="col-lg-12 col-12">
                            <img class="width-10" src="/image-500x1000px.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is my sample code.
I hope there are people who can help me solve my question. Thank you.

Want to images tops and bottoms are on the same horizontal line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a 100% width, responsive, non-Bootstrap solution. It’s simple enough to do without Bootstrap, so why make it more complicated than it needs to be?

The problem with your sample image is that the maths doesn’t work if there is a gap between the images. Do you want the tall image on the right to be a little taller than 1000px to account for the gap between the first and second rows? Or do you want the wide image at the bottom left to be a little shorter than 500px instead? Either is possible.

I went with the first option, having the tall image be a little taller. So I have placed it inside a container which then allows me to use `object-fit: cover;`.

```css
body {
  margin: 20px;
}
.layout {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(0, 1fr));
  gap: 20px;
}

.layout>*:nth-child(3) {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
}

.layout>*:nth-child(4) {
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
  grid-column: 3;
}

.layout img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.layout>*:nth-child(4) img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/500">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/500">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/500">
  <div>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/1000">
  </div>
</div>
```